# Account Abstraction userop with initcode and no calldata

Tags: account-abstraction

Suppose one wants to submit a UserOp that contains initCode but no callData.
What would happen?

The use case is to create a record in a factory of an 'account' but not create the actual account contract until the user wants to 'spend' [some of] the balance. Obviously, because of counterfactual contract creation, this should be viable.